# What is stopping us from stick building a space station?

Tags: astronomy, space-travel, space-mission

I want to understand why we do not build space stations in a similar way that we build a home, piece by piece. Instead we construct modules on the ground and fly them up. Are there some technical limitations other than money that make this impossible?

Why don't we fly up raw materials, prefabbed metal panels, structural steel and any other material and slowly construct a space station that is suitable for somewhat normal living, normal sized rooms, ceiling heights, etc.?

I'm wondering if any plans exist or working groups are exploring this idea. Or is it a technical limitation, for example: not being able to ensure a complete seal between the exterior pieces?

Is what I am wondering clear?

Comment: Stick building isn't even the most efficient way to build here on Earth. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefabricated_home ---- http://www.monolithic.com/

Comment: "What is stopping us?" Idiots who rule the world...

Answer (score 16):

Somebody has to put the pieces together somewhere.

If you do it in the ground, you can work in shirtsleeves, with easy access to supplies, tools, equipment, and other workers.  If you need a tool, you can probably walk next door to get it, or ask someone to bring it to you.  If you drop a tool, you can pick it up.

In orbit, you have to work in a bulky pressure suit, with perhaps one or two other astronauts helping, with everything you use costing thousands of dollars per kilogram and months of advance planning to get to orbit.  And if you drop a tool, it can float away and be lost (and have to be tracked by NORAD).

The more assembly work you can do on the ground, the easier and cheaper the entire process is going to be, likely by several orders of magnitude.

The optimal method is to assemble things on the ground in modules as big as you can carry into orbit, and (if necessary) assemble the modules as simply as possible once you get there.  This is why the International Space Station consists largely of connected modules, each of which fits in a Shuttle cargo bay.  (Thanks to dmckee for pointing this out.)

Comment: *The more assembly work you can do on the ground, the easier and cheaper the entire process is going to be* modulo there being a lift platform that can orbit the finished product, of course.

Comment: @dmckee: Good point; I've updated my answer.

Comment: The finite size of cargo bays is also why many space structures unfold or inflate in space.

Comment: @Andrew An example being the Galileo, due to the smaller rocket compartment (which wasn't in the original plan, I _think_ this was nothing more than political), later causing significant problems when the folding antenna got stuck unfolding ~24hrs before the data was becoming available. http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/about_JPL/jpl101.pdf

Comment: Well, if you drop a tool, wait exactly one orbit, position yourself in the exact same place, and open hand. The tool will conveniently present itself for you to grab it. Of course, assuming it doesn't hit anything meanwhile, and you don't have to apply orbital corrections.

Comment: @FlorinAndrei: It will return to the same place, but not necessarily at the same time you do if its orbit has a (slightly) different period.

Comment: People will one day want to go to space and have more than a cylindrical module to stay in.

Comment: @opensourcechris: I agree completely -- but current technology and economics mean that cylindrical modules are *much* cheaper than anything else.  Pioneers in North America had to build log cabins before they could build skyscrapers.

Comment: We need to get the space agencies and automotive manufacturing engineers together. Robots could probably do much of the work.

Comment: @opensourcechris: Not worth it until you're going to build more than a handful of them, and *that* is not worth it until you have the capacity to *launch* more than a few. The cost of putting mass in orbit is the single biggest impediment to doing anything really interesting in space, and it is arguably the case that NASA is the single biggest impediment to bringing the cost down (not their fault, but they are at the mercy of congresscritters for funding...).

Answer (score 5):

The most comparable thing would be constructing a submarine, not a house. Let's bring a few things to consider.

1. They must be air tight.
2. They have complex electronics to regulate systems.
3. They both operate in non-typical environments.

Submarines are typically constructed in dry docks, and then placed in the water. That way they can get everything welded when it is easy to do so, and won't have problems with constructing in an extreme environment.

Comment: Great example!!